# boostrap div with variable column length

Tags: bootstrap-4

In my HTML page , i have 2 parties 
the second part is not always displayed.

I want that if the 2nd part is not displayed, the 1st takes 100% of the width of the page
my code :

```
<div class="container-fluid  d-flex flex-row">
  <div>
      1st part
  </div>
   <div [hidden]="viewDetails()">
       2nd part
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-grow-1`...

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-grow-1">
        1st part
    </div>
    <div>
        2nd part
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/qfncUNIpEq

Another option is to use the Bootstrap Grid (as shown in the Codeply) and the `col` class which also applies `flex-grow:1` to the column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with using the col class in bootstrap. It uses as much space as available:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"> Some content </div>
  <div class="col"> Some content </div>
</div>
```

If both "cols" are in the code, each occupies 50% of the space, if only one is present, the col stretches over 100%.
You can also give one col a fixed with with, for example: `col-md-2`, the other `col` class will then span the rest of the available space.